# singular solution of the partial differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, singular-solution

What is the singular solution of the equation $pq=z$ or $z_{x}*z_{y}=z$ ? İts complete integral is $2*\sqrt{z}=x*\sqrt{a}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{a}}+b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the singular solution,we need to differentiate both sides of the complete integral wrt $a$ and $b$ parameters.So, wrt   $a$
$$0=\frac{x}{2\sqrt{a}}-(1/2)ya^{(-3/2)}$$
and wrt $b$
$$0=1$$
Because we have a contradiction from the last equation, there is no singular solution of the problem.